# Possible to symlink a file to a web url?

Tags: linux

We currently have a challenge where the ideal solution would be to symlink a file to a web URL...

image.jpg -> http://www.host.com/images/image.jpg

Is this possible?

Comment: How about a FUSE filesystem? There is [httpfs2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/httpfs/files/httpfs2/) I tried it just now. Buggy, (e.g. claims to have a `-f` option, but doesn't recognize it) but seems to work.

Comment: httpfs2 looks interesting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a named pipe that you feed with a wget for the file?

Edit - Not wget.  You can work with linx -dump.  So -

```
mkfifo reddit
links -dump reddit.com > reddit
cat reddit
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several nice and interesting solutions here. I especially like @ArjunShankar's fuse solution. In the spirit of keeping it simple though, perhaps a file in `/etc/cron.daily` with

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /your/dir && wget -N http://www.host.com/images/image.jpg
```

would be a lot simpler and Good Enough(TM)?

Answer (score 2):

On mac I successfully used this great tool by maxogden, which also using FUSE:
https://github.com/maxogden/mount-url

```
brew install osxfuse
npm install -g mount-url
```

Then

```
mount-url "https://url-to-10-gb-video-file-on-some-external-cloud-storage/video.mp4?xxx=yyy"
```

This would create a symlink for the file named `video.mp4` in the current directory.
Not too fast access speed, but works.